# Planes don't show assigned colors/ images

Tags: image

[image: Edit: asked to add a pic of nodes.][image: Image as plane is active]

I am having trouble using assets from blender 2.79b I personally made for a project. I made sure the user preferences and add-ons in 2.81 were the same ones I used in the older files. Screenshot is what I see when I open an older file. I made sure all files were there and mapped accordingly. There is about 2 hundred images parented into this scene. This problem appears in all of my other .blend files last saved in version 2.79b.

Is there something I am overlooking? Or am I going to have to re-import all images and rig everything back up to use these assets? I can provide more images if needed.

Comment: Did this issue occur in blender 2.79b? If so then this isn't an issue. If it didn't then change it to rendered view and see is the issue continues.

Comment: No, it did not have this issue in 2.79b. Render preview is the same as the image I posted. It's supposed to look like two guys in a gym. All I get is grey planes.

Comment: Try putting a normal Diffuse Bsdf (Not Principled) does it still give the same thing. If so then check if the light are strong enough.

Comment: Is that in nodes or drivers? I have no idea how to use those. Or how to access that part of the program.

Comment: Nodes not drivers.

Comment: Diffuse BSDF node is not an option.

Comment: Could you post an image of your node setup?

Comment: I just added a pic of the nodes. Had to enable them. Nodes is something I have no experience with. I actually started to search for the Diffuse BSDF node returned no options. Also this is 2.80 beta as 2.81 gives me driver errors and won't open.

Comment: Okay there you are in Compositing where you can add in after effects. By node editor I'm talking about Shader editor(They Changed a lot in 2.8). Could also be and issue that you are in Look dev (Material View) in look dev a lot of things are excluded in look dev mainly like textures and displacements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem:**
You are using the *Compositor Editor*.
This will never work, you need to use the *Shader Editor*.

**How to:**
1) Open the *Shader editor*.
2) Select your object and click the <kbd>+ New</kbd> button, to add a new material.
3) Add an Image texture node and select your image.

Open your Shader editor.
With your object selected, click the *New material* button.
[image]

Add the *Image Texture* node, and connect it like this.
Then click <kbd>Open</kbd> and find your image texture.
[image]

This is the result.
If you want to see it, you need to be in the *Material Preview* or *Rendered Preview.*
[image]

---

If you're a beginner, I wholeheartedly reccomend [BlenderGuru's Donut tutorial series for beginners](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLjEaoINr3zgEq0u2MzVgAaHEBt--xLB6U).
Spend some time there, and you'll learn much more :).

Good luck! :)

Comment: The donut Series is one among many and they are all good.